# Pass in parameters in django query

Tags: python, django

Here is my case:

I have different types of users to share one general view, but I want return different fields for them. I used `values()` to specific fields, like this `values('f1', 'f2')`, and it returned the queryset.

Then, I wanted to use a variable to store the fields to query, and pass it in the `values()`, but failed. My snippets look like this:

```
list = ('f1', 'f2')
e = Entity.objects.all().values(list)
```

I tried tuple, list, str, but all failed.

Error msg:

> object has no attribute 'split'

What is the correct way to get this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [unpack the list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
fields = ('f1', 'f2')
e = Entity.objects.all().values(*fields)
```

Also, do not name a variable as `list` - it shadows built-in varaible type:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> a
[]
>>> list = ('f1', 'f2')
>>> a = list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, it works, really helps me a lot.

Actually, I use another name for the variable, just change to `list` for the question, I'll pay attention next time.